# Cannot resolve the "e" in e.getKeyCode();

Tags: keyevent

im trying to implement a Key Event, but eclipse can't resolve the "e" in e.getKeyCode();

What am I missing here?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qryCe.png)

Comment: Did you mean to access `arg0` instead of `e`? `e` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `e` defined in your code. You have your method signature as:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0)
```

Either change `arg0` to `e` or vice versa.